# "mount: /dev/mqueue: must be superuser to use mount" when starting a Yocto Linux system via NFS and TFTP

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto, nfs

I followed the guide "[Yocto NFS & TFTP boot](https://community.nxp.com/t5/i-MX-Processors-Knowledge-Base/Yocto-NFS-TFTP-boot/ta-p/1103671)" from the i.MX knowledge base to make my embedded Linux device run a kernel and a filesystem on my development machine.

The kernel seems to be correctly loaded via TFTP, but the system doesn't boot up properly and `systemd` goes into maintenance mode.

Here's the first error in the log:

```
[   10.637534] systemd[1]: dev-mqueue.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited, status=32/n/a
[   10.657077] systemd[1]: dev-mqueue.mount: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
[   10.666907] systemd[1]: Failed to mount POSIX Message Queue File System.
[FAILED] Failed to mount POSIX Message Queue File System.
See 'systemctl status dev-mqueue.mount' for details.
```

It seems similar to the log included in [an unanswered comment](https://community.nxp.com/t5/i-MX-Processors-Knowledge-Base/Yocto-NFS-TFTP-boot/tac-p/1103676/highlight/true#M821) in that same guide.

Looking into `systemctl status dev-mqueue.mount` I see:

```
* dev-mqueue.mount - POSIX Message Queue File System
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dev-mqueue.mount; static)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2022-03-06 11:52:40 UTC; 5h 29min ago
      Where: /dev/mqueue
       What: mqueue
       Docs: man:mq_overview(7)
             https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/APIFileSystems

Mar 06 11:52:40 pico-imx7 mount[180]: mount: /dev/mqueue: must be superuser to use mount.
Notice: journal has been rotated since unit was started, output may be incomplete.
```

Not sure what's wrong, or why the system would fail like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message `must be superuser to use mount` is a hint to a permission problem.

The Linux system expects most system files to be owned by UID 0 (root), but when reading the NFS filesystem set up in the guide it actually reads UID 1000, or the UID of whoever built the system in the development machine. If I list the contents of `${YOCTO_BUILD_DIR}/tmp/work/${TARGET}-poky-linux-gnueabi/${IMAGE}/1.0-r0/rootfs`, I get:

```
drwxr-xr-x 20 1000 1000 4096 Mar  9  2018 ./
drwxr-xr-x 14 1000 1000 4096 Mar  5 19:19 ../
drwxr-xr-x  2 1000 1000 4096 Mar  9  2018 bin/
drwxr-xr-x  2 1000 1000 4096 Mar  9  2018 boot/
drwxr-xr-x  2 1000 1000 4096 Mar  9  2018 dev/
drwxr-xr-x 59 1000 1000 4096 Mar  9  2018 etc/
drwxr-xr-x  4 1000 1000 4096 Mar  9  2018 home/
drwxr-xr-x 10 1000 1000 4096 Mar  9  2018 lib/
drwxr-xr-x  2 1000 1000 4096 Mar  9  2018 media/
drwxr-xr-x  2 1000 1000 4096 Mar  9  2018 mnt/
drwxr-xr-x  4 1000 1000 4096 Mar  9  2018 opt/
drwxr-xr-x  2 1000 1000 4096 Mar  9  2018 proc/
drwxr-xr-x  2 1000 1000 4096 Mar  9  2018 run/
drwxr-xr-x  3 1000 1000 4096 Mar  9  2018 sbin/
drwxr-xr-x  2 1000 1000 4096 Mar  9  2018 srv/
drwxr-xr-x  2 1000 1000 4096 Mar  9  2018 sys/
drwxr-xr-t  2 1000 1000 4096 Mar  9  2018 tmp/
drwxr-xr-x 38 1000 1000 4096 Mar  9  2018 unit_tests/
drwxr-xr-x 11 1000 1000 4096 Mar  9  2018 usr/
drwxr-xr-x  9 1000 1000 4096 Mar  9  2018 var/
```

Notice the `1000` as UID and GID.

Compare that with the listing of the filesystem image tarball, made with `tar --exclude=\*/\*/\* --no-wildcards-match-slash -tjvf ${YOCTO_BUILD_DIR}/tmp/deploy/images/${TARGET}/${IMAGE}-${TARGET}.tar.bz2`:

```
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2018-03-09 13:34 ./
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2018-03-09 13:34 ./bin/
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2018-03-09 13:34 ./boot/
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2018-03-09 13:34 ./dev/
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2018-03-09 13:34 ./etc/
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2018-03-09 13:34 ./home/
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2018-03-09 13:34 ./lib/
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2018-03-09 13:34 ./media/
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2018-03-09 13:34 ./mnt/
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2018-03-09 13:34 ./opt/
dr-xr-xr-x 0/0               0 2018-03-09 13:34 ./proc/
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2018-03-09 13:34 ./run/
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2018-03-09 13:34 ./sbin/
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2018-03-09 13:34 ./srv/
dr-xr-xr-x 0/0               0 2018-03-09 13:34 ./sys/
drwxrwxrwt 0/0               0 2018-03-09 13:34 ./tmp/
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2018-03-09 13:34 ./unit_tests/
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2018-03-09 13:34 ./usr/
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2018-03-09 13:34 ./var/
```

Here the root directories are correctly owned by `root`.

The same permissions are in the `.ext4` image file, that is part of the SD/MMC image file.

Two possible solutions:

- mount `${YOCTO_BUILD_DIR}/tmp/deploy/images/${TARGET}/${IMAGE}-${TARGET}.ext4` file as loop in a directory, then export that directory via NFS (might require root privileges);
- extract `${YOCTO_BUILD_DIR}/tmp/deploy/images/${TARGET}/${IMAGE}-${TARGET}.tar.bz2` in a directory, then export that directory via NFS; will require root privileges and some more time to extract the embedded filesystem.